# webelement.click() method is not working with chrome in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My chrome version is Version 68.0.3440.106 selenium version is 3.13. Below is code snippet.

Tried using the normal Xpath and Java script execution as well. Still no luck please help with this.

I am trying perform click action on the below button name " Submit"

[image: Inspect element view]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit'and @class='btn wb-btn-default center-block']")).click();


WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit'and @class='btn wb-btn-default center-block']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", ele); 



JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js1.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", "//button[@type='submit'and @class='btn wb-btn-default center-block']");
```

Comment: Are you able to click that button manually? Also, Please post the error log you are getting along with the HTML code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am able to click button manually. I am not seeing any error after the scripts execution.

Comment: @Venkatesh What is innerText of Button element.

Comment: I have the same issue. It was working fine earlier, but after an auto software update last night it stopped working. Were you successful in finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code, As per your summary I understood button name is Submit, in case it is different, please replace the actual text in contains section of Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and contains(text(),'Submit')]")).click();
```

Comment: I tried this code , unfortunately it didn't work. Changed the contains text with other options. Still it doesn't click.